# Оптимизация кода C++ для быстродействия

Tags: c++, оптимизация

у меня есть код который находит самое кратное двух чисел добавляет их и выводит в консоль, мне нужно оптимизировать код чтобы он работал как можно быстрее, я пробовал это сделать, но у меня выводит только 4 и 10, несмотря на то какие я числа вписываю.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int a, b, i=101, d=-1, m=-1;
cout<< "Set the positive number a:";
cin>> a;
cout<< "Set the positive number b:";
cin>> b;
for (int i=2; i<a; i++)
  if (a%i==0)
  {
  d=i;
  }
for (int i=2; i<b; i++)
  if (b%i==0)
  {
  m=i;
  }
  if (d>0)
   {
   if(m>0)
   {
    i=d+m;
    cout<< " Result:"<<i;
   }
   else
       cout<< "NONE";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что тебе нужно просто НОК найти?

Answer (score 4):

Так, не хотел влазить, но ответ предыдущего оратора мне не нравится.

Во-первых, не нравится *рекурсивным* вычислением `gcd` (кстати, в стандарте С++ в `<numeric>` имеется готовая функция [`gcd()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd), можно использовать ее, как и готовую функцию [`lcm()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm)). Но я понимаю, что такое учебное задание :)

Во-вторых, не нравится вычислением

```
(a * b) / gcd(a,b)
```

которое может привести к переполнению с большей вероятностью, чем

```
(a / gcd(a,b)) * b
```

Так что я бы писал примерно так (хотя на самом деле я бы использовал шаблоны):

```
int gcd(int m, int n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}

int lcm(int m, int n)
{
    return (m/gcd(m,n))*n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы, в начале, находил НОД, при помощи рекурсии, а потом уже НОК, используя простую формулу:

---

(a * b) / НОД

---

Также, нужно не забыть сделать проверку на нулевые значения, иначе вылезет ошибка, так как в функции gcd есть деление.

---

P.S. В функции gcd используется тернарный оператор, почитайте, как он работает.

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >>b;
    if (a == 0 || b == 0){
        cout << "Enter correct values";
    }
    else{
        cout << (a * b) / gcd(a, b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Только не так: `(a * b) / НОД`, а так: `(a / НОД)* b` — это две очень большие разницы!!